# Does JDBC have a relative path option when using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'd like to load a text file that is located in a NetBeans project folder.

What is the default relative path (if one exists in `JDBC`) of the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` command? (`MySQL` syntax)

I would have assumed it would be the home directory of the compiled code - but it has given me the expected SQL exceptions for not being able to find the file.

I have to hand in an assignment - and so cannot use an absolute path as that would not work on another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) for `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`:

> If LOCAL is specified, the file is read by the client program on the client host and sent to the server. The file can be given as a full path name to specify its exact location. **If given as a relative path name, the name is interpreted relative to the directory in which the client program was started.**

You should try using the location of the client program as being the start of the relative path.  The directory of the compiled code does not seem to have anything to do with this.

Comment: Your solution is fantastic, and I apologise for not doing further research to obtain it from the official tutorial.  However:  the relative path does seem to be the directory of the code (NetBeans project directory in my case).  It didn't work initially because I was running the project from a command line, in which case it was System32 (I've just discovered, maybe that would be obvious to experts.)  Finally, it doesn't work when placed in the bin folder storing NetBeans.exe, or any other obvious folder there.

Comment: Should have also mentioned I was running from cmmd prompt, that would have been pertinent information to experts on here.

Comment: @E.Rowlands This is interesting.  So it appears that when you running from NetBeans the relative path was the code directory, which makes sense since Eclipse would launch Java from that location.